# iOS location based push notifications filtering

Tags: ios, geolocation, apple-push-notifications

I am working on iOS application, with the requirement of a manager inserting coordinates and radius on server-side, which should trigger a push notification on every device in that particular radius.

I was planning to deliver the notification to all devices, apply client-side filtering and only show the notification for the relevant devices. However I just found out that once the notification is sent to APNS there is no way to prevent it from appearing on the phone.

What are my options to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can send a silent push notification to all users using the 
"content-available" : 1
value in the aps payload

Example here:

http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications